# What is the Camel endpoint for marshalling using bindy dataformat?

Tags: java, apache-camel, bindy

I have a requirement to dynamically create camel-bindy endpoint for marshalling the input. Below is the sample code:

```
<dataFormats>
  <bindy id="bookModel" type="Csv" classType="org.camelcookbook.transformation.csv.model.BookModel"/>
</dataFormats>
<route>
  <from uri="direct:unmarshal"/>
  <!-- <unmarshal ref="bookModel"/> -->
  <to uri="dataformat:bindy:unmarshal?ref=bookModel"/>      
</route>
```

Instead of unmarshal tag , I need to pass exchange to the equivalent end-point but getting error "Cannot find dataformat with name bindy"

Comment: I will be using "recipientList" to dynamically route the message to appropriate bindy marshaller.

Comment: Have you add camel-bindy as dependency to your classpath.

Comment: Yes, Claus. It has been added

Comment: The below one works fine : <unmarshal ref="bookModel"/>

Comment: SO, are you saying unmarshal works but marshal does not work?

Comment: sorry for any confusion. In the example code, I am trying unmarshal using dataformat endpoint for bindy which is not working. The tag unmarshall works fine

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple bindy data formats: csv, fixed length, key-value pair.

Their respective data format names to use with the "dataformat:" endpoint uri are:

- bindy-csv,
- bindy-fixed,
- bindy-kvp

So in your case you should specify unmarshalling like so:

```
<to uri="dataformat:bindy-csv:unmarshal?ref=bookModel"/>
```